# Comparação de datas da database com data do sistema

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

Olá!

Preciso comparar o mês de cadastro de informações presentes em uma tabela do banco de dados com o mês atual fornecido pelo sistema.

No banco de dados eu cadastro em uma coluna o número referente ao mês. Por exemplo:

No dia 16/12/2016 cadastrei um produto, na tabela consta o nome do produto, preço e número do mês. Preciso somar os valores dos produtos do mês atual, ou seja, os preços dos produtos do mês fornecidos pelo sistema através desse código:

```
string mes = DateTime.Now.Month.ToString();
```

Portanto, se no mês de dezembro cadastrei 10 produtos com preço de 10 reais preciso que o sistema compare a coluna 'mes' do banco de dados com o mês do computador, realize a soma dos valores da coluna 'preco' cuja linha seja o mês em questão.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo que entendi, você quer o valor do banco para o c#, certo?

Então, segue um código ilustrando como retornar do banco o valor somado de **todos** os produtos do mês retornado pelo sistema.

```
string mes = DateTime.Now.Month.ToString();
string pesquisa = "SELECT SUM(Preco) FROM PRODUTOS WHERE MES = " + mes;
using (System.Data.IDbCommand comando = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(pesquisa, DBconn))
{
   object resultado = comando.ExecuteScalar();
   ValorTotal.Text = Convert.ToString(resultado);
}
```

O valor somado será armazenado na propriedade `Text` do controle `ValorTotal`.
A forma de conexão ao banco foi apenas um exemplo.

Comment: Modifiquei de acordo com meu código e deu certo! Agradeço!